# Aviation Statistics Sources

Tags: accident-statistics, statistics

Are there any online, publicly available sources of aviation statistics, like:

- number of manufactured aircrafts by type and year
- number of registered aircrafts by type and year
- number of aircraft incidents by type and year
- etc.

I'm aware of [Annual Reports of General Aviation Manufacturers Association](https://gama.aero/facts-and-statistics/statistical-databook-and-industry-outlook/), but this data is just for general aviation and it doesn't contain numbers before year 1990.

Comment: I don't think resources location is in the scope as defined by the [help center](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

You wont find a single source for any of these things but you can find *some* of the info form fairly reliable sources:

- [The NTSB publishes accident data by type and year](https://www.ntsb.gov/_layouts/ntsb.aviation/index.aspx) but this is only for US accidents or accidents involving US aircraft that they can investigate overseas.
- The FAA allows you to lookup by [make and model](https://registry.faa.gov/aircraftinquiry/acftref_inquiry.aspx) and would allow to get some info on registered aircraft but again only for the US.
- [ICAO also lists their final reports online](https://www.icao.int/safety/airnavigation/AIG/Pages/E-library-of-Final-Reports.aspx) which give a more global picture of whats going on but you will still need to combine all the data. [They also offer some rolled up stats.](https://www.icao.int/safety/iStars/Pages/Accident-Statistics.aspx)

All of these sources generally can get spotty before the 80's for a few reasons. A lot of those reports only existed on paper and are still being digitized so results are intermittent. Official governing bodies started at different times around the globe and even paper reporting took time to standardize, accidents that pre-date that may have gotten lost in the mix.